# Getting MethodMissingException in Reflection .net

Tags: c#, reflection

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Processor
{
    public class InvoiceProcessorTest
    {
        public void Process(String entity)
        {
            GenerateInvoice generateInvoice = new GenerateInvoice();
            generateInvoice.Process(entity);
        }
        public string ProcessTest(String str)
        {
            return "testString";
        }
    }
}
```

My code to read method is

```
Assembly processorAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("ProjectDLL.dll");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

Type myType= processorAssembly.GetType("Processor.InvoiceProcessorTest");
object myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

Console.WriteLine((string)myType.InvokeMember("ProcessTest", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, myObj , new object[] { "Pramod" }));
```

I want to call ProcessTest method of the InvoiceProcessorTest class.

**`myType.GetMethods()`** shows me both method from the class.

**But when I InvokeMember, it returns a missing MethodException. Namespace.InvoiceProcessorTest.ProcessTest not found**

Comment: What's `submitOfferType`? A short but *complete* example would really help here.

Comment: Just check this first http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2004/02/13/debugging-a-missingmethodexception-missingfieldexception-typeloadexception.aspx

Comment: Your first code block calls your class `Processor.InvoiceProcessorTest` but the second one assumes it is `Namespace.InvoiceProcessorTest`. This would however lead to different errors then the one your describing so i suspect one of these code blocks is not the same as you are using.

Comment: @jan-peter vos and @jon skeet i was showing sample of my project. please find update code

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Console.WriteLine((string)myType.InvokeMember(.........
```

Use mytype.InvokeMember

Comment: Umesh i have used same in my application here i posted sample code

Comment: just check if you are using correct(latest) ProjectDLL.dll. I checked ur code its working fine